# AngularJS e Angular no mesmo projeto

Tags: angularjs, angular

Atualmente tenho um projeto que está em AngularJS que decidimos atualizar para Angular 6. Porém, fazer esta atualização de uma vez só é inviável devido ao tamanho do projeto.

Existe uma forma de manter AngularJS e Angular na mesma aplicação?
Como fazer isto ? Procurei em alguns sites, mas não achei nada concreto sobre o assunto, apenas artigos para "migrar".

Comment: Utilize o módulo Upgrade para lhe auxiliar com o processo: https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html